# Название с LIst добавить в ComboBox

Tags: c#, list, combobox

Всем хай
Вообщем проблема небольшая
Как можно Doc передать в функцию AddData?
Я просто через вторую форму даю Doc какой то текст, но оно далее не присваивает последней колонке DataGridView
Я в функции DoctorName передаю текст в Doc
А потом по сути этот Doc должен пойти в функцию где 5 параметров с Doc

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public string Doc { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        dataGridView1.ColumnCount = 5;
        dataGridView1.Columns[0].Name = "Имя пациента";
        dataGridView1.Columns[1].Name = "Фамилия пациента";
        dataGridView1.Columns[2].Name = "Возраст";
        dataGridView1.Columns[3].Name = "Диагноз";
        dataGridView1.Columns[4].Name = "Лечащий врач";
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AddData(textBox1.Text,textBox2.Text,textBox3.Text,textBox4.Text);

    }

    private void AddData(string name,string lastName,string age,string diagnose)
    {
        string[] data = { name, lastName, age.ToString(), diagnose};
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);

        Form2 formDoctor = new Form2();
        formDoctor.Show();

    }

    private void AddData(string name, string lastName, string age, string diagnose,string Doc)
    {
        string[] data = { name, lastName, age.ToString(), diagnose,Doc };
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(data);
    }

    public void DoctorName(string DocName)
    {
        Doc = DocName;
    }



    private void dataGridView1_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        char ch = e.KeyChar;
        if(!Char.IsDigit(ch) && ch !=48)
        {
            e.Handled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Укажите, что именно вы используете `WPF` или `WinForms`.

Comment: WinForms
Но я уже вроде как нашел, в Form2 просто comboBox1.Items.Add("sdad"); Хотя почему то так делал и не выходило

Answer (score 0):

```csharp
private List<string> doctors = new List<string>();
private void SetItem()
{
    doctors.Add("Lena");
    doctors.Add("Michael");
    comboBox1.DataSource = doctors;
}

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SetItem();
}
```

Comment: А в чем смысл перевода в `Array` (`ToArray()`) ? Я не сильно знаком с `WinForm`, может чего не знаю. По сути ведь, это лишнее?

Comment: Названия методам нужно давать согласно [CamelCase](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/CamelCase.svg/368px-CamelCase.svg.png), а не как у вас.